# How to get the esp32s2 recognized as USB device?

Tags: esp32, usb, midi

I have an esp32-S2 saola and I am trying to use it as a MIDI usb device. I am trying to use this github repository: https://github.com/chegewara/EspTinyUSB. I am able to run the code on the esp32s2 saola and I am connecting to a mac with a USB cable to pins 19 and 20 but don't get any MIDI input in my computer (mac), in fact my computer is not recognizing the device.

So I guess my actual question is about how to get the esp32s2 recognized as a USB device by the mac. Any clues of what might be happening? Or should connecting  to pins 19 and 20 be enough and I am dealing with a hardware bug?

For the usb cable I took a usb only-power cable apart and then rewired it so it was only data (two middle cables connected to pins 19 and 20). As it was not working I then connected also the usb's power and ground cables with no luck:

[image: Soldered USB for esp32-S2]

EDIT: This the documentation for the USB driver on the esp32-S2 and why I think the power cables might not be needed at all (which I tried but didn't work): https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/peripherals/usb.html

Comment: Pretty grizzly looking.  I'm not really following the whole scheme.  It would be helpful to see everything a diagram.  As is, I'm only guessing you swapped the power for data on both sides of the cable.  That you actually have a ground back to the USB port etc.  You are not seeing anything like an overcurrent event on the USB host?

Comment: On the other side of the cable (not shown in the picture) I removed a micro usb male header and ended up with bare cable going to pins 19 and 20 as per the diagram I found in the documentation: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-reference/peripherals/usb.html

Comment: This goes back to what I said above.  "That you actually have a ground back to the USB port etc."  Circuits work better when they're.... circuits.